# Batch file that copies files from an external device into a specific folder

Tags: batch-file

I would like to create a batch file that copies files froma an external device into a specific folder, but I want it to copy from all external devices avaible and not have to define a letter variable to each device. 
These are my two options:

```
@echo off
cls&echo 0
md c:\system 
xcopy %~d0 c:\system /S /I /C
exit
```

---

```
@echo off
md c:\system 
xcopy D: c:\system /s
xcopy E: c:\system /s
xcopy G: c:\system /s
xcopy F: c:\system /s
exit
```

In the second one i would have to specify all device variables (not wanted)

I found `%~d0` would make the file copy to any device connected but it only copies the files in the folder the batch is located at.

Comment: Do you want to looking for the letter drive when you plug an USB Key for example ?

Comment: @Hackoo Yes, exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a for loop with the [wmic logicaldisk](http://en.code-bude.net/2013/02/23/show-all-drives-in-command-prompt/) command to get a list of your drives and then you will be able to run the xcopy command for each of your drives.

Example:

```
for /f "skip=1" %%b IN ('wmic logicaldisk where drivetype^=2 get deviceid') DO xcopy %%b c:\system /s
```

Note: the example looks only for removable drives (`where devicetype^=2`), here is the devicetypes definitions from the link above, you can modify the syntax of the wmic command to return just the drives you want, if you want it to return all drives just remove the `where devicetype^=2`

- 0 = **Unknown**
- 1 = **No Root Directory**
- 2 = **Removable Disk**
- 3 = **Local Disk**
- 4 = **Network Drive**
- 5 = **Compact Disc**
- 6 = **RAM Disk**

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much worked for me, though as I commented I have 5 removable devices and as I only have one connected it shows a window when it doesn't find the rest of the drives. No problem anyway does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Ok just plug your USB Key and give a try for this code and let me know if this did the trick or not ?

```
@echo off
Mode con cols=98 lines=10 & Color 9E
Title Searching the Drive letter of your USB Key by Hackoo 2015
set TargetFolder=c:\system
if not exist %TargetFolder% MD %TargetFolder%
echo.
ECHO   *******************************************************************************************
echo.
echo                           Searching the drive letter of your USB Key .......
echo.
ECHO   *******************************************************************************************
wmic logicaldisk get DeviceID,DriveType /Format:CSV > %Tmp%\tmp.txt 
for /f "skip=2 tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in ('%COMSPEC% /a /c type "%Tmp%\tmp.txt"') do echo %%b %%c >> %Tmp%\tmp2.txt
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('%COMSPEC% /a /c type "%Tmp%\tmp2.txt" ^|Find "2"') Do (set MyUSBDrive=%%i)
Del %Tmp%\tmp.txt & Del %Tmp%\tmp2.txt
cls
echo.
ECHO   *******************************************************************************************
echo.
echo                          The drive letter of your USB Key is  %MyUSBDrive%
echo.
ECHO   *******************************************************************************************
pause 
cls
xcopy %MyUSBDrive% %TargetFolder% /S /I /C
pause
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort but when I run it it says %MyUSBDrive% is K: when it is G:. When I run wmic logicaldisk I get C:, D: and E: as hardrives and G:,H:,I:,J:, and K: as external devices maybe it takes K: because it's the last one? No idea

Answer (score 0):

I improve a little my last code to get all your connected external devices
Check it and let me know if this later did the trick or not

```
@echo off
Title The copy of all your connected external devices by Hackoo
Mode con cols=100 lines=20 & Color 9E
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set TargetFolder=C:\TestCopy
wmic LOGICALDISK where driveType=2 get deviceID > wmic.txt
for /f "skip=1" %%b IN ('type wmic.txt') DO (
XCopy %%b\* !TargetFolder!\ /dsicfy)
Del wmic.txt
pause
```